# What is the difference between --no-cache and --rm when building a Docker image

Tags: docker

After I was accidentally filling up disk space, with building Docker images one after one (same/iteration), I started searching, if there is a workaround?
Even if I stopped the containers and deleted them, there is no space left on HDD. (Here I used`docker image prune`)

I was wondering, if adding `--rm` in future Docker build commands would solve my problem?
Can `--rm` and `--no-cache` be used in the same build command? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

`--rm` after building the final image, removed the intermediate containers (this is the default behaviour).

`--no-cached` tells to docker to don't use cached intermediate layers and regenerate them as well. Each instruction inside a docker file generates an intermediate layer, for example `RUN apt install -y some-package`. In the above scenario, the default behaviour is to reuse the generated intermediate layer without download and installing again `some-package`. Instead, sometimes, you may need to refresh the intermediate layers with more recent stuffs, so you have to use the `--no-cache` option.

Comment: Note that changing the content of files that are `COPY`ed into the image or changing `ARG` values will invalidate the cache as well.  Except in the specific case of OS package updates that happen very early in a Dockerfile, you shouldn't usually need `--no-cache`.